# ASP.net, Is the Accordian Pane even necessary?

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

When using the [Accordian control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Accordion/Accordion.aspx) from the MS Ajax control toolkit, do I even need to use the Panes?  It seems that I can use HeaderTemplate and ContentTemplates to display my data without having to use any AccordianPanes at all.  Is this recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Panes are basically the wrappers for the content. So in the example Accordion on that site, there are four panes (Accordion, AutoSize, etc). If you don't use any panes, there will only be one giant pane with no collapse / expand feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you use data binding, you don't need to define panes. You just use HeaderTemplate and ContentTemplate, and ASP .Net will create the panes for you. In the templates you include the data binding expressions.

I don't see a way of not using AccordionPanes without using data binding. But there might be one.